# Senario based questions

Tags: trigger

There is one field called count field in parent object, is it possible through workflow to update the child records when ever we creating record in parent object ??

Comment: Take a look at [declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)...

Comment: If you are creating a new record in parent then how do you have child record?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the process builder. Create a process for your child object for when created, then an action to update a record related to your child object and select the parent>children.

Comment: That only works if there is a relationship though. Doesn't necessarily sound workable here. Not that OP has given remotely enough detail to answer properly.

Comment: @AdrianLarson they mentioned parent record and child record, I would assume that means their is a relationship. Agreed there is not enough info.